# Android Activity Back Stack Navigation issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have researched numerous posts regarding Activity back stacks, as well as the Android Developer website, but still can't find a solution to a problem I'm having.

**Scenario:**

I have `Activity A`, I navigate to `Actvity B`, from A  and then press the back button to go to `Activity A` again:

`Actvity A` --> `Activity B` --> `Actvity A`

Nothing out of the ordinary..

**Problem**

When I press the back button to go to from `Activity B` --> `Activity A`, `Activity B` is not destroyed straight away, as expected it goes into a pause state and this is where I have strange problem. If I want to return to `Activity B` from `Activity A` and **IF** `Activity B` is still in a pause state all its life cycle methods are called when use `startActivity(B)` from `Activity A`:

`Activity B` - `onCreate()` > `onPause` > `onStop` > `onDestroy` <-- why is this happening

At this point, to me it shouldn't exist anymore, and I can't explain why it went through all its lifecycle methods, rather than just the start initialisation lifecycle methods. The fall out from this strange behaviour is that the Activity is still visible on screen but doesn't populate a `RecyclerView` which in first initialisation did so as expected. At this point if I press back `Activity B` enters a pause state again.

If `Activity B` is in a pause state (`Activity A` is at top of stack) and the framework ends `Activity B` through lifecycle callbacks and I  navigate to `Activity B` again from A it works as expected (RecyclerView is populated), basically a fresh instance always works fine.

All I can assume, when referring to the Activity Lifecycle diagram, is that `Activity B` enters a pause state, however is destroyed without calling `onStop`, `onDestroy` etc.. meaning any Activity clean up operations I have in those callbacks aren't happening?

**Things I've Tried**

Changing various `Intent` filters, and combinations, when starting `Activity B`:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Calling `finish()` when `onBackPressed()` is called in `Activity B`

Various other fingers crossed and hope changes, nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help please!

Comment: remove `super.onBackPressed()` from `onBackPressed()`  in **Activity A** below is the code for `onBackPressed()`    `@Override public void onBackPressed() { moveTaskToBack(true); }`

Comment: @jatDevta I'm not sure how this will change anything, Activity A, is not a problem.  Secondly I have a navigation draw in Activity A, adding this `moveTaskToBack(true);` to `onBackPressed()` method will just close the app, instead of closing the navigation drawer, if its open and I press back?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the answer to the problem - not obvious at first, but now I understand what was happening.

The root cause of the problem was to do with 2 instances of the same Activity (`Activity B`) referencing the same Objects (Objects supplied from DI library).

Firstly when returning to `Activity A` from `Activity B`, `Activity B` was not immediately destroyed, and this causes a complication - this instance would never be reused, however still existed for a period of a few seconds.  In this situation when using startActivity(B) from `Activity A` it would create a new instance and destroy the old (hence why I was seeing logging in both creation and activity ending callbacks), if it still existed.  In this scenario both instances were sharing the same object, and this object "cleaned up" the Activity when destroyed.  So  the object (Presenter in this case) was being told by the old instance that it should clean up the Activity as its being destroyed, however this was not the case, because a new instance had been created.

**The solution**

Quite simple really, every time a new instance of `Activity B` was created, store in the Presenter a unique number (startId), and when `Activity B` called `onDestroy()` pass its current unique number, and check they match - if they don't match its not the latest instance, so do nothing.  Very similar idea when you want to stop a Service, and check its the latest Activity calling the service from the startId.

Personally I don't know why Activities aren't destroyed straight away on pressing back, but thats the reason why this was happening.